# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/contacts/avatars/000/000/001/original/2yiOPBoSBag.jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Запускаю на локалхосте RoR-приложение, ввожу URL-адрес, по которому расположено сохраненное изображение, а в ответ получаю ошибку, указанную в заголовке.

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/system/contacts/avatars/000/000/001/original/2yiOPBoSBag.jpg"):
>   actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
>   actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`call'
>   railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app' railties
>   (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged' railties (5.1.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`call' actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in`call' rack
>   (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call' activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in`
>   call' actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in`call' rack
>   (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call' railties (5.1.4)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in`call' puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call' puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:624:in`handle_request' puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client' puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:302:in`block in run' puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

В браузере:

> {"status":404,"error":"Not
>   Found","exception":"#\u003cActionController::RoutingError: No route
>   matches [GET]
>   \"/system/contacts/avatars/000/000/001/original/2yiOPBoSBag.jpg\"\u003e","traces":{"Application
>   Trace":[],"Framework Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in
>   `call'"},{"id":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`
>   call'"},{"id":2,"trace":"railties (5.1.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"},{"id":3,"trace":"railties
>   (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`block in
>   call'"},{"id":4,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in
>   tagged'"},{"id":5,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged'"},{"id":6,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in
>   `tagged'"},{"id":7,"trace":"railties (5.1.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`call'"},{"id":8,"trace":"actionpack
>   (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in
>   `call'"},{"id":9,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in`
>   call'"},{"id":10,"trace":"rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in
>   `call'"},{"id":11,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in`
>   call'"},{"id":12,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in
>   `call'"},{"id":13,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in`
>   call'"},{"id":14,"trace":"rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in
>   `call'"},{"id":15,"trace":"railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in`
>   call'"},{"id":16,"trace":"puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'"},{"id":17,"trace":"puma
>   (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in`
>   handle_request'"},{"id":18,"trace":"puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'"},{"id":19,"trace":"puma
>   (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in`block in
>   run'"},{"id":20,"trace":"puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in
>   `block in spawn_thread'"}],"Full Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"actionpack
>   (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in`
>   call'"},{"id":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in
>   `call'"},{"id":2,"trace":"railties (5.1.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in`call_app'"},{"id":3,"trace":"railties
>   (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in
>   call'"},{"id":4,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`block in
>   tagged'"},{"id":5,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged'"},{"id":6,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`
>   tagged'"},{"id":7,"trace":"railties (5.1.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":8,"trace":"actionpack
>   (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in`
>   call'"},{"id":9,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in
>   `call'"},{"id":10,"trace":"rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`
>   call'"},{"id":11,"trace":"activesupport (5.1.4)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in
>   `call'"},{"id":12,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`
>   call'"},{"id":13,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in
>   `call'"},{"id":14,"trace":"rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`
>   call'"},{"id":15,"trace":"railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in
>   `call'"},{"id":16,"trace":"puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in`call'"},{"id":17,"trace":"puma
>   (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in
>   `handle_request'"},{"id":18,"trace":"puma (3.11.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:438:in`process_client'"},{"id":19,"trace":"puma
>   (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in
>   run'"},{"id":20,"trace":"puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in`
>   block in spawn_thread'"}]}}

Чем это может быть вызвано? Я долго гуглил эту ошибку, все пишут, что в файле production.rb необходимо написать:

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

однако ни к чему это не привело. rails assets:precompile тоже вводил - проблему, опять же, не решило.

Comment: Так а есть ли оно там вообще?

Comment: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] " - проверьте всетаки правильный ли путь указан. Проверьте что картинка лежит по адресу "/YOUR_APP_PATH/public/system/contacts/avatars/000/000/001/original/2yiOPBoSBag.jpg", "assets:precompile" - прекомпиляция ассетов, на файлы в '/public' это не влияет